# Excel VBA - Copy table data from website and put into excel?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to copy a table from a website and put this into excel.
My table can be identified by the elementID "VisibleReportContentctl32".

For some reason, my code produces this error:
'object required'

on this line: Range("A1").Text = dat

Here's my full code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetSSRSData()

    Dim IE            As Object: Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim TR_Elements   As Object
    Dim TR            As Object ' Table Row
    Dim TD_Elements   As Object
    Dim TD            As Object ' Table Data
    Dim RowNumb       As Integer
    Dim Columns       As Integer
    Dim ColumnNumb    As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim dat As String

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("http://gbrlon02-sql-17/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fCutlass+Reports%2fManagement+Reporting%2fForwardOrdersSticksOnly+-+ForecastVariance+(Monthly+Report)")

         Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
             DoEvents
         Loop

         If IsObject(.Document.getElementById("VisibleReportContentctl32_ctl09")) Then
            dat = IE.Document.getElementById("VisibleReportContentctl32_ctl09").innerHTML
            Range("A1").Text = dat
         Else
            MsgBox "doesn't"
         End If
   End With
End Sub
```

please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: are you really sure that you identified the failing line correctly?  .... try to single-step the code

Comment: is the URL that you posted correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Power Query][Table from web] is simple and stable

Answer (score 0):

That URL doesn't work for me.  Your code should look something like this...

```
Option Explicit 
Sub gethtmltable() 
    Dim objWeb As QueryTable 
    Dim sWebTable As String 
     'You have to count down the tables on the URL listed in your query
     'This example shows how to retrieve the 2nd table from the web page.
    sWebTable = 2 
     'Sets the url to run the query and the destination in the excel file
     'You can change both to suit your needs
    Set objWeb = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _ 
    Connection:="URL;http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/default.php", _ 
    Destination:=Range("A1")) 

    With objWeb 

        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables 
        .WebTables = sWebTable 
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 
        .SaveData = True 
    End With 
    Set objWeb = Nothing 
End Sub
```

You just need to identify which specific table you want to import data from.